# Cannot GET /index in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a server named "app.js" which display many pages of my web site.

```
var http=require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    // routes
var route = require('./route');



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

server.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("server listen at localhost:3000");});
app.get('/', route.index);
```

route.js:

```
var index = function(req, res, next) {
   if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.redirect('/index');
   } else {

      var user = req.user;

      if(user !== undefined) {
         user = user.toJSON();
      }
      res.render('menu', {title: 'Home', user: user});
   }
};
module.exports.index = index;
```

The folder of project:

```
/interface
      /views
            index.ejs
      app.js
      route.js
```

How can I fix it ? what is the mistake in my program?

Comment: I'd try sending the index file without route and without ejs first.

Comment: Do you mean that maybe the problem from file index??

Comment: Atm, the problem can come from ejs, router, rendering, authenfication system and/or express. I'd send the index file using only express. If it works, add authenfication, then if it works, add ejs.

Comment: I tried this:app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs'));
});I got the page without css style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.get` is unreachable after `server.listen`.

Place it before:

**app.js:**

```
var http=require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    // routes
var route = require('./route');



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// here:
app.get('/', route.index); 

server.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("server listen at localhost:3000");});
// app.get('/', route.index); <= not here
```

When not authenticated, redirection is not what you want, but:

**route.js:**

```
// res.redirect('/index');
res.render('index');
```

Comment: Could you give us error details? It will be easier to fix it then.

Comment: I just got cannot get /index

Comment: Maybe the problem is with "app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));" because when I wrote app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs')); }); I got the page.

Comment: `res.redirect('/index');` won't render but redirect it explains `you cannot get /index`.